# Grub консоль при каждом запуске

Tags: linux, grub, kubuntu

Поставил на домашний компьютер в качестве основной системы `kubuntu`, до этого стояла `ubunta`. с ней таких проблем не было. `ubuntu` загружала `grub loader` - где предлагала несколько вариантов запуска системы, при этом сама выходила из экрана и продолжала загрузку системы по таймауту.

Сейчас при каждом запуске `kubuntu` запускается `grub` консоль. То есть не просто выбор вариантов запуска, а просто `grub` консоль. Консоль не выходит из себя по таймауту, я обязательно должен ввести `exit` - чтобы продолжить загрузку системы.

вот такой дистрибутив :

```
cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

версия grub :

```
grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.04-1ubuntu26.4
```

grub config:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nomodeset"
```

Comment: Вы бы лучше не версию показали, а конфиг grub

Comment: @DiD не подумал об этом, отредактировал вопрос.

Comment: grub установлен не правильно, не видит своего конфига.

Comment: @eri, а почему когда он вводит exit, система продолжает грузиться?
обычно когда выходишь из консоли восстановления - ничего не загружается

Comment: какое приглашение консоли? есть строчки перед приглашением?

Comment: @eri grub console "номер версии" и дальше примерно такие строки : minimal BASH-like console... еще пара предложений и поле ввода.

Comment: конфига нет. сделай update-grub

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если консоль `grub >` - grub установлен не правильно, не видит своего конфига.

Загрузитесь в ОС или чрутнитесь с лайв диска:

```
mkdir -p /target/
mount /dev/sda1 /target/
mount -B /dev /target/dev
mount -B /sys /target/sys
mount -B /proc /target/proc
chroot /target
. /etc/profile
mount -a
```

И выполните команды

```
update-initramfs  -u
grub-install /dev/sda
update-grub
```

Для efi еще подключте efi раздел и установите grub режиме x86_64-efi, но скорее всего будет достаточно `update-grub`